# EM Field tensor of a point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, reissner-nordstrom-metric

If I say the [Reissner-Nordstrom metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric)
$$
ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}+\frac{e^2}{r^2}\right)\text d t^2 + \left( 1-\frac{2m}{r}+\frac{e^2}{r^2}\right)^{-1}\text d r^2 + r^2 \text d \Omega^2
$$
is the solution of the Einstein equation $G_{\mu\nu}=8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$ of a point charge, where 
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\left( F_{\alpha\mu}F^\alpha_{\phantom \alpha \nu} - \frac 1 4 g_{\mu\nu} F^{\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta } \right)\;,
$$
what does $F$ look like? Of course I need to write down $F$ for a point charge with mass $m$ and charge $q$. In one source I found that for a point charge we have
$$
A = A_\mu \text d x^\mu =  \frac e r \text d r\;,
$$
where 
$$
F_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\mu A_\nu - \nabla_\nu A_\mu\;.
$$
But when I calculate it, I find:
$$
F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu \left( \delta_{\nu r}\frac{e}{r} \right) - \partial_\nu \left( \delta_{\mu r}\frac{e}{r} \right) = -\frac e r^2(\delta_{\nu r}\delta_{\mu r} - \delta_{\mu r}\delta_{\nu r}) = 0\;.
$$
So $F$ of a point charge is zero?

Comment: I have no idea what you did in your last equation, but the field strength of a point charge is certainly not zero, since $E^i = F^{i0}$, and the electric field of a point charge is certainly not zero.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote this question ;-) . In the last equation I used the fact that $\nabla_\mu A_\nu - \nabla_\nu A_\mu = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ and $A_\mu = \frac e r \delta_{\mu r}$.

Comment: Try $A=\frac{e}{r}dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If four vector notation is less intuitive then refer back to three vectors
\begin{align*}
\vec{E} &= - \vec{\nabla}\phi - \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t} \\
\vec{B} &= \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}
\end{align*}
For a static point particle 
\begin{align*}
\vec{E} &= \frac{e}{r}\hat{r}\\
\vec{B} &= 0 
\end{align*}
The solution up to gauge transformation is what you already know
\begin{align*}
A_o &= \phi = \frac{e}{r}\\
\vec{A} &=0
\end{align*}
Or $A = \frac{e}{r}dt$. There for as @Holographer suggested the appropriate potential should be $A_\mu = (\frac{e}{r}, 0 ,0 , 0)$